# Find zero of function $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{cos(x(n+1))}{n!}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, summation, roots

I'm interested in finding the smallest positive zero of function
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{\cos(x(n+1))}{n!},\qquad  x\in\mathbb R$$
It is approximately equal to $0.832$. I've calculated Taylor series expansion of this sum, which is:
$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}e \cdot\frac{(-1)^k \ B_{2k}\ x^{2k}}{(2k)!}$$
Where $B_n$is n-th [Bell number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_number).

But I don't know, whether it helps.
Thanks for all the help in solving this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your sum is equal to
$$\Re\bigg(\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{e^{ix(n+1)}}{n!}\bigg)$$
or
$$\Re\exp\big(ix+e^{ix}\big)=\Re\exp\big(\cos x+i\sin x+ix\big)$$
Using Euler’s formula, this is equal to
$$e^{\cos x}\cos(x+\sin x)$$
To find when this is equal to zero, you must compute the zeroes of the function
$$\cos(x+\sin x)$$
or the values of $x$ for which
$$x+\sin x = \pi(n+1/2)$$
for some $n\in\mathbb Z$. I do not suspect an elementary solution will exist, but you can use this explicit form to calculate some pretty good approximate solutions.

The smallest of the zeroes will occur when
$$x+\sin x = \pi/2$$
which is at approximately $x\approx 0.832$. See @Raymond’s answer for a more accurate approximation and a representation in terms of the Dottie number.

Comment: (+1) Neat exposition. Note that the substitution of $\,\displaystyle y:=\frac{\pi}2-x\;$ in your last equation gives the simple $\,\cos(y)=y\,$ i.e. the Dottie Number. Cheers,

Answer (score 3):

The more exact value is $\;0.83171119357973597757600960396587803808517294078679544552179166\cdots
$ which is equal to $\;\dfrac{\pi}2-D\;$ with $D$ the ["Dottie Number"](https://oeis.org/A003957).

The Dottie number is obtained by iteration of the $\cos$ function on a calculator (in 'radian' mode) as detailed in [Mathworld](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/DottieNumber.html).

Comment: Wikipedia [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dottie_number).